# Format-Table out of Two Lists?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I've had this idea about getting the output from 2 separate functions, that return a `PSCustomObject` as a *list*, and formatting them into one table. My problem is simple... I don't know how to do it. lol

With the various of combinations that I tried, here's whats given me some promising results:

```
$Var1 = [PSCustomObject]@{

    UserName = $env:USERNAME
    Stuff1   = 'stuff1'

} | Format-List | Out-String -Stream


$Var2 = [PSCustomObject]@{

    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Stuff2       = 'stuff2'

} | Format-List | Out-String -Stream 



[PSCustomObject]@{

TableOne = $Var1.Trim().Foreach({$_})
TableTwo = $Var2.Trim()

} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**The output:**

```
TableOne                                       TableTwo                                                      
--------                                       --------                                                      
{, , UserName : Abraham, Stuff1   : stuff1...} {, , ComputerName : DESKTOP-OEREJ77, Stuff2       : stuff2...}
```

I say promising in the respect that it shows the actual content of `$var1` and 2, whereas my other attempts didn't. I also left the `.foreach()` operator there to show one of the many many different tricks I tried to get this working. For a quick second I thought the `Out-String` cmdlet would've done the trick for me, but was unsuccessful.

Has anyone ever done something similar to this?

**EDIT:**
*Nevermind, I figured it out.*

Used a `for` loop to iterate through each line assigning it the the `PSCustomObject` one at a time. Also used the `.Where()` operator to remove white spaces, and compared the two arrays to find the largest number to use it as the count.

```
$Var1 = $([PSCustomObject]@{

    UserName = $env:USERNAME
    Stuff1   = 'stuff1'

} | Format-List | Out-String -Stream).Where{$_ -ne ''}


$Var2 = $([PSCustomObject]@{

    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Stuff2       = 'stuff2'
    ExtraStuff   = 'More'

} | Format-List | Out-String -Stream).Where{$_ -ne ''} 

$Count = ($Var1.Count, $Var2.Count | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
 
$(for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{

    TableOne = $Var1[$i]
    TableTwo = $Var2[$i]

    } 
}) | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Output:**

```
TableOne           TableTwo                      
--------           --------                      
UserName : Abraham ComputerName : DESKTOP-OEREJ77
Stuff1   : stuff1  Stuff2       : stuff2         
                   ExtraStuff   : More
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting way to format two collections with corresponding elements.

To indeed support two collections with *multiple* elements, a few tweaks to your approach are required:

```
# First collection, containing 2 sample objects.
$coll1 = 
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    UserName = $env:USERNAME
    Stuff1   = 'stuff1'
  },
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    UserName = $env:USERNAME + '_2'
    Stuff1   = 'stuff2'
  }

# Second collection; ditto.
$coll2 = 
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Stuff2       = 'stuff2'
    ExtraStuff   = 'More'
  }, 
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME + '_2'
    Stuff2       = 'stuff2_2'
    ExtraStuff   = 'More_2'
  }

# Stream the two collections in tandem, and output a Format-List
# representation of each object in a pair side by side.
& { 
  foreach ($i in 0..([Math]::Max($coll1.Count, $coll2.Count) - 1)) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      TableOne = ($coll1[$i] | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() + "`n"
      TableTwo = ($coll2[$i] | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() + "`n"
    } 
  }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

The above ensures that multiple objects are properly placed next to each other, and yields something like the following:

```
TableOne                              TableTwo
--------                              --------
UserName : jdoe                       ComputerName : WS1
Stuff1   : stuff1                     Stuff2       : stuff2
                                      ExtraStuff   : More
                                     
UserName : jdoe_2                     ComputerName : WS1_2
Stuff1   : stuff2                     Stuff2       : stuff2_2
                                      ExtraStuff   : More_2
```

Comment: Ahh, very neat! I like this approach as it only formats the objects in just the last `PSCustomObject` \ Output. Thank ya!